# C# XNA How to tell if object is moving to target on X and Z Axis

Tags: c#, vector, xna

So I have an Object and a target. They both have X and Z positions that change over time.

I keep track of there current position and previous position.
The positions can be positive or negative.

I am currently trying to figure out a method to tell if an object is moving towards the specified target.

This is the code I am working on

```
    if ((Math.Abs(this.previousPosition.X) - Math.Abs(this.currentPosition.X)) > Math.Abs(target.currentPosition.X)
        && (Math.Abs(this.previousPosition.Z) - Math.Abs(this.currentPosition.Z)) > Math.Abs(target.currentPosition.Z))
    {
        //is moving to target
        return true;
    }
        //is not moving to target
        return false;
```

Comment: Basically `(this.previousPosition - this.currentPosition).Magnitude < target.currentPosition.Magnitude`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am using a Vector3 which doesnt have magnitude, Is .Length the same thing?

Comment: yes but actually there is a `Vector3.Distance` static member that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Have you considered breaking that massive if-statement condition into variables so you can actually read and understand what's going on? `var deltaX = Math.Abs(this.previousPosition.X) - Math.Abs(this.currentPosition.X);` and so on. Can be helpful and in many cases the compiler will optimize any unnecessary ones away.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to compare the distance between 'this' and the target, like this:

```
private bool IsApproachingTarget(double epsilon)
{
    float prevDist, currDist;
    Vector3.DistanceSquared(ref this.previousPosition, ref target.previousPosition, out prevDist);
    Vector3.DistanceSquared(ref this.currentPosition, ref target.currentPosition, out currDist);
    return IsLess(currDist, prevDist, epsilon);
}


[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
/// <summary>
/// Robust implementation of a &lt; b, handling floating point imprecisions
/// </summary>
public bool IsLess(double a, double b, double epsilon)
{
    return a < b - epsilon;
}
```

Note that I used [Vector3.DistanceSquared](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196325.aspx) instead of Vector3.Distance. It's a common performance trick, that if you only want to compare the magnitude of vectors and you are not interested in the actual magnitude to skip an unnecessary square root calculation like this.

Morever, you can store the result in each game loop, because this way the distance calculations are made twice...

And Vector3.DistanceSquared measures [Euclidean distance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), maybe a simple [Manhattan distance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) would do for you as well.

The [MethodImpl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute is just an extra optimization feature introduced in .NET 4.5. You can skip it if you target earlier .NET Framework versions.